# How to delete time from Firebase timestamp in ios swift?

Tags: swift, timestamp, firebase-realtime-database

How can I check to see if my "timestamp" value is a day older than the current time and delete the entry from Firebase?  As example how would I know if `1480561776458` was more than 24 hours ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let components = DateComponents()
let startDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970:addServerStamp/1000)
let roundTimeLeft = startDate.addingTimeInterval(60*60*24)
let currentDate = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
    components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .day, .minute, .second], from: currentDate , to: roundTimeLeft)
```

This is what I used to create the time left from a time stamp. If the user created something, the post(the user created) would be active for responses(by other users) for 24hours after the post.
This might not be exactly what you are looking for but it should help you go in that direction.

Once you get your timestamp stuff handled it is just a matter of sending the command to firebase DB to delete the entry once a certain amount of time has passed.